# unable to call exe using python

Tags: python

I am calling an exe (which is dependent on other batch files) , Python is giving error.
 I am able to call exe (which is independent)

what I am doing is..

```
import os
os.system("notepad.exe")    # is working
```

but

```
os.system("c:/ank.exe")     # this is giving error as ank.exe is dependent on other batch     files
```

Comment: What error? More details please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to first change the current directory so that the executable you want to run can find its dependencies:

```
target = "c:/ank.exe"
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(target))
os.system(target)
```

otherwise, `os.system()` executes in the directory of the running script.

Comment: I did that still os.system is returning 1, and no output is getting displayed.. Actually I am calling OpenEv.exe(converted openEV batch file to exe) and the path for that is        target = "C:/Program Files/FWTools2.4.7/openev.exe"    and the rest of the steps as same as you have mentioned still i doesn't work